# Data Migration from Java Hibernate SQL Server to Python Mongo Stack

Tags: mongodb, migration, database-migration, data-migration

I have one live website with multiple active users(around 30K) and each of them have their own configuration to render there homepages. The current stack of the portal is Java Spring Hibernate with SQL Server. Now, we have re written the code in Python MongoDB stack and want to migrate our users to new system. The issue here is that the old and new code will be deployed on the separate machines and we want to run this migration for few users as part of Beta Testing. Once the Beta testing is done, we will migrate all the users.

What would be the best approach to achieve this? We are thinking about dumping the data in alternative file system like XML/JSON on a remote server and then reading it in the new code.

Please suggest what should be the best way to accomplish this task

Comment: Are you migrating your users from one MongoDB system to another, or from SQL Server to MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

**Import CSV, TSV or JSON data into MongoDB.**

It will be faster and optimal to dump the file in a format like json, txt or csv , which should be copied to the new server and then import the data using mongoimport, in the command line shell.

Example
mongoimport -d databasename -c collectionname  < users.json

Kindly regard to the link below for more information on mongoimport if you need to
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoimport/

Comment: So you are suggesting to generate json file for each model from old code in the new code format and thn run mongoimport with those files

Comment: How to get CSV or JSON from MSSQL?